# Java. Получение типа из дженерика от родительского класса

Tags: java, generics

Я пытаюсь получить класс из дженерика тип которого был определен в классе родителе и делаю это так:

```
public class Generic<T> extends Generic1<T> {

    Object[] objects;
    int index;

    public void f1(int size) {
        this.objects = new Object[size];

        Class<T> t = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        try {
            T value = t.newInstance();
            System.out.printf("string " + value);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(t.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic<String> g = new Generic<>();
        g.f1(3);
    }
}

class Generic1<String> {

}
```

И мне кажется что все должно работать. Но оно падает с следующим исключением:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.TypeVariableImpl cannot be cast
>   to java.lang.Class    at generic.Generic.f1(Generic.java:13)  at
>   generic.Generic.main(Generic.java:26)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Помогите разобраться, что я здесь упускаю? И почему `ClassCastException`?
Помогите поправить код до рабочего состояния.

Comment: Вы вообще не можете его получить, type erasure же. Конкретно в данном случае у вас вообще возвращается TypeVariable, что очевидно не является конкретным классом.

Comment: Да но я слизал этот код с туториала в котором он работал. Я точно уверен что тип жденерика можно получить если он в суперклассе указан. Я сам видел как это работало...

Comment: Ну, во-первых, он здесь не указан в суперклассе. Во-вторых, вы сможете его получить только в том случае, если код скомпилируется с явным указанием типа, что сразу говорит вам о том, что вы можете забыть об этом методе, потому что у вас нет контроля над компиляцией. Это, если мне не изменяют перетолки, возможно в том случае, если какой-то класс указывает в родителях дженерик с проставленным типом (и это может оказаться враньем), но **возможно**, а не **обязательно**, и это все равно никогда не покроет всех случаев. В-третьих, ваша задумка вычисления типа в рантайме заранее обречена на провал ->

Comment: потому что type erasure все равно выстрелит, а если вы взяли первый элемент в коллекции, и он имеет пять типов в иерархии, то какой из них является дженериком?

Comment: >>>Ну, во-первых, он здесь не указан в суперклассе<<< как это не указан а class Generic1<String> а потом public class Generic<T> extends Generic1<T> почему не указан? Не извините но вы не правы, я видел как этот код работал на видео, но я что-то упустил, когда я найду что именно я обязательно вам тоже расскажу))))

Comment: У вас там указан параметр T, а не тип

Comment: class Generic1<String>

Comment: @Павел пожалуйста, дайте ссылку на источник кода.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman это видео моего ментора я не буду его заливать на ютуб но если скините почту я вам отправлю. Но я выяснил у него в чем дело, etki был прав что надо написать public class Generic<T> extends Generic1<Strintg и тогда> все работает а из сигнатуры родителя(прям самого класса родителя - файла) действительно никак. спасибо за потдержку всем ^

Comment: @Павел оформите это как ответ и примите его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было в том что в родительском классе `Generic1<T>` не было указанно никакого типа, должно быть не `class Generic<T> extends Generic1<T>` а правильно это :  `class Generic<T> extends Generic1<String>`. Тогда все работает. И хотел бы отметить что метод `getActualTypeArguments()` возвращает массив всех типов в дженерике родительского класса и если бы было на пример `class Generic<T> extends Generic1<String, Integer>` то по нулевому индексу был бы `String` а по первому `Integer`.

```
public class Generic<T> extends Generic1<String> {

    Object[] objects;
    int index;

    public void f1(int size) {
        this.objects = new Object[size];

        Class<T> t = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        try {
            T value = t.newInstance();
            System.out.printf("string " + value);
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(t.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic<String> g = new Generic<>();
        g.f1(3);
    }
}

class Generic1<String> {

}
```